# Loading HTML templates with Angularjs and Rails

Tags: angularjs, templates, ruby-on-rails-4

I cannot get my template load in my Rails app with Angularjs. Following is my setup

```
#app/assets/javascripts/app.js
app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'templates'])
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
});

#app/assets/javascripts/templates/home.html
<h1>abc</h1>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require angular/angular
//= require angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree ./templates
//= require_tree .

#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<body ng-app="app">
<div ui-view=''></div>
```

and I'm getting the following error

```
http://localhost:3000/home.html 404 (Not Found)
```

But if I use `template` instead of `templateUrl`, and give inline HTML it works fine.

I'm using `angular-rails-templates-0.1.3` and `rails-4.2.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the version of `angular-rails-templates` had a bug, which was fixed in 0.1.4 (https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates/issues/95). So updating your gem to a newer version should fix the bug.

Try updating your version of `angular-rails-templates`

I would not suggest manually placing `'/javascripts/templates/home.html'` (or the correct form: `'/assets/javascripts/templates/home.html'`), since this is part of the assets pipeline.

**EDIT:** If Sprockets 3+ is required -- e.g. for ES6 Javascript syntax -- you will have to look into a different fix. A couple potential fixes are suggested in this thread: https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates/issues/93 . However, the maintainers of the `angular-rails-templates` project seems to be having some trouble solving this issue.

Though mcasimir's suggestion of replacing `angular-rails-templates` with a simple Ruby initializer and a few lines of JS code might do the trick, if upgrading `angular-rails-templates` (/downgrading `sprockets`) is not an option https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates/issues/93#issuecomment-109953596

Comment: thanks for the answer (and sorry for late acceptance , didnt have a time to work on this) , I followed the issue #95 and I had to downgrade `'sprockets', '2.12.3'` and it started working. quick question though, what are your thoughts on depending on a old version of `sprockets` , going forward ?

Comment: It depends on your use-case. Some libraries depend on sprockets 3, so if you need any of those, you might have issues. That said, it looks like `angular-rails-templates` understands this and is actively trying to push for a fix. I think I'd go with whatever's simplest right now, rather than worry too much about it. Ultimately, it probably wouldn't be too difficult to sub-out `angular-rails-templates`, or any other middle-ware, if it stops being useful.

Comment: That said, if you're really worried, you could always add an App-wide namespace to your template references: `templateUrl: appConfig.templatesNamespace + 'home.html'`, which you could always sub out for something like `"/assets/javascripts/templates/"`. I personally wouldn't go that route, just because it seems too much like a solution waiting for a problem (what's the point?), and also seems like other devs maintaining the code might abuse it.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I hear your point . I shouldn't overthink the problem right now , `If it ain't broke, don't fix it` :D

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
templateUrl: 'home.html'
```

to:

```
templateUrl: '/javascripts/templates/home.html'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but still the same `http://localhost:3000/javascripts/templates/home.html 404 (Not Found)` ;(